# how can I view the c code generated from my pypy program

Tags: disassembly, pypy

Many language environments allow one to "disassemble" a provided function.  Since Pypy compiles to C-code (if I understand things correctly).  then it seems natural to be able to see a C-code dump from an expression, or a whole python file.

Can I do this?  how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPy does not compile python bytecode to C code. The tracing JIT replaces a frequently used piece of code with generated machine code (assembly). You can turn on [logging](https://rpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html) to save the JIT traces to a file and view them with vmprof or jitviewer.